# Сортировка, массив php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть двумерный массив. Формируется он так:

```
$arr[] = ($value2["COUNT(product_id)"].":".$value['manufacturer_id']);
```

Вид массива исходного массива для сортировки:

```
$array = array(
    array(0 => 7:1),
    array(0 => 1:2),
    array(0 => 5:3),
    array(0 => 2:4),
)
```

Можно ли его отсортировать по первому значению до двоеточия? Чтобы получился массив вида:

```
$array = array(
    array(0 => 7:1),
    array(0 => 5:3),
    array(0 => 2:4),
    array(0 => 1:2),
)
```

Comment: `7:1` это тип `string` да? я правильно понял?

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan да

Comment: у вас тут опять тот же косяк. вы приводите здесь не 1 массив, а 4 массива. я вам там в чатике отписался

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант с `usort`:

```
<?php

    $array = [['7:1'], ['0:2'], ['0:3'], ['0:4'], ['13:5']];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);
    usort($array, function($a, $b) {
        $a = explode(':',$a[0]);
        $a = $a[0];
        $b = explode(':',$b[0]);
        $b = $b[0];
        return (int)$b - (int)$a;
    });
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($array);

?>
```

А это то что выводит `print_r`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13:5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7:1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0:4
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0:3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0:2
        )

)
```

Comment: `foreach ($result2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    $arr[] = ((int)$value2["COUNT(product_id)"].":".(int)$value['manufacturer_id']);
    }  

     usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
        $a = explode(':',$a)[0];
        $b = explode(':',$b)[0];
        return $b - $a;
    });

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);` `Array
(
    [0] => 7:1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0:2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0:3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0:4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 13:5
)` Ничего :с

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков поменял на ваш массив, и все нормально работает, скинул новый результат `print_r` в ответ.

Comment: не работает т.к. одномерный массив в ответе, а в вопросе двумерный массив.

Comment: @Sergey Не обратил внимание, извиняюсь, сейчас поменяю ответ.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan `{
     foreach ($result2 as $key2 => $value2) {
    $arr[] = ($value2["COUNT(`product_id`)"].":".$value['manufacturer_id']);
    }  


    usort($arr, function($a, $b) {
        $a = explode(':',$a[0]);
        $a = $a[0];
        $b = explode(':',$b[0]);
        $b = $b[0];
        return (int)$b - (int)$a;
    });
    echo '<pre>';

    print_r($arr);`
Полный код, ничего не изменилось в итоге

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков сделайте `print_r` массива до сортировки.

Comment: @МолюскаМоллюсков Если у вас массив формируется в таком виде ( `$array = [['7:1'], ['0:2'], ['0:3'], ['0:4'], ['13:5']];` ) то не возможно что бы не работало.

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция [arsort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.arsort.php)

> arsort — Сортирует массив в обратном порядке, сохраняя ключи

```
$array = ['7:1', '1:2', '5:3', '2:4'];
arsort($array);
var_dump($array);
```

Возвращает true при успехе. Принимает ссылку на массив

Comment: ничего не произошло
`array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "7:1"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "0:2"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "0:3"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "0:4"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "13:5"
}`

Comment: можете код показать? добавьте в свой ответ

Comment: вначале вопроса есть формирование массива

Comment: там выходит  4 массива.

Comment: У вас каким-то образом получаются 4 массива вместо одного.

Comment: верно, непонятно почему

Comment: ага у вас есть $arr и $array и  $array формируется из $arr  так?

Comment: Вы  $arr и $array гдето мержите?